# Access child component variables within ng-container

Tags: angular, ng-template, ng-content

I have a custom component called Suggestion List, which displays a list of Suggestions to the user from an observable. I have created this component as generic as possible so you can pass any array of data, so I'd like to be able to customize the display of it from the parent as I'll never know for certain what the objects will look like until implementing it. Unfortunaly I can't access the child components variables from the parent in ng-container.

Is this possible with ng-container or ng-template or should I be taking another route altogether?

Parent Component

```html
    <suggestion-list (suggestionSelected)="selectSuggestion($event)" [$suggestions]="$suggestionSource">
      <ng-container>
        {{suggestion.firstname + ' ' + suggestion.lastname}}
      <ng-container>
    </suggestion-list>
```

Child Component

```
  <mat-list role="list">
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let suggestion of $suggestions | async">
      <mat-icon mat-list-icon>person</mat-icon>
      <mat-card (click)="selectSuggestion(suggestion)">
        <ng-container></ng-container>
      </mat-card>
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use `ng-template`. You can define a template for each element in the parent component and display the template in the child component for each element in the array:

Parent component:

```
<suggestion-list (suggestionSelected)="selectSuggestion($event)" 
                 [suggestions]="$suggestionSource | async" 
                 [suggestionTemplate]="suggestionTemplate">
</suggestion-list>

<ng-template #suggestionTemplate let-suggestion>
<span>{{suggestion.firstname + ' ' + suggestion.lastname}}</span>
</ng-template>
```

And in your child component you could just do (notice that we pass the suggestion var in the template through the implicit context of the `ng-template`:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let suggestion of suggestions>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="suggestionTemplate; context: {$implicit: suggestion}"></ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

In the .ts file of the child component, you declare the template passed in like:

```
@Input() suggestionTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

PS: I've written this code right now, so it's not tested, but I think you can get an idea of what you can do!

Comment: This worked, only thing I did differently was in the child component:
`<mat-list role="list">
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let suggestion of suggestions">
      <mat-icon mat-list-icon>person</mat-icon>
      <mat-card (click)="selectSuggestion(suggestion)">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="suggestionTemplate; context: {$implicit: suggestion}"></ng-container>
      </mat-card>
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>`
So I could keep my mat-list

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vggk6r) is the working example

parent.component.html

```
   <div>
     <suggestion-list (suggestionSelected)="selectSuggestion($event)" [$suggestions]="$suggestionSource">
       <p>{{suggestion.firstname + ' ' + suggestion.lastname}}</p>
     </suggestion-list>
   </div>
```

child.component.html

```
   <div>
     <ng-content></ng-content>
     <p>Hello !</p>
   </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly that doesn't work, the parent component still has no idea what suggestion.firstname or lastname is in it's contex

Comment: I added a working example for it. But we have to think about that also, if you are getting suggestion data from your backend you have to use ng-container also.